# Deserialize mongoid documents with YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, yaml

I'm testing a important functionality for a web application with a mongoid document. THe object (which is a mongoid document) is serialized used YAML, but when I try to load it using YAML again, I obtain a Hash

How can I deserialize correctly the document in order to get my instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is convert the document to YAML and how is it doing it? What is trying to load the YAML and how is it doing it? Why are you even using YAML in a MongoDB environment?

Comment: I am using delayed_jobs for AWS SQS. If I am not wrong, the gem serializes an performable method along with an instance using JSON and YAML, in order to generate a message for the queue.

Then, it opens the message and performs a JSON.load and a YAML.load to obtain the instance and perform the delayed method. However, as I verified using the rails console, If I invoke a object.to_yml on an mongoid::document object and then use YAML.load to open the result, I won't obtain the instance but a Hash with the instance attributes. To summarize I need YAML.load to return an instance, not a hash.

Comment: Are you using `delayed_job_mongoid`? I avoid trying to serialize whole models when using DJ, too much room for problems when you do that (assuming you can even get it to work when database connections and other non-serializeable state is involved). I just serialize IDs and load fresh models out of the database.

Comment: I tried, but delayed_job_mongoid is for serializing the models in a mongoDB, isn't it?. As a requirement, I must use an amazon SQS service (so, I hace a delayed_job_sqs gem with certain modifications). But the problem remains and I don't have the option of using the mongoDB to stack my delayed jobs.

Comment: Then don't serialize whole Mongoid models, serialize just their IDs and reload them from MongoDB in the DJ.

Comment: That's the thing, I can obtain the ID and serialize it, but I'm trying to find a way to look for the model in the base from the gem, without hardcoding it. I'm still strugging to know how to code that in ruby precisely.

Comment: Can't you store the class name in a string and `constantize` it?